# Why does the base-emitter voltage in NPN transistor become constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, electric-circuits, voltage, semiconductor-physics

[image]

The setup above shows the experiment that I have been working with. During the experiment, the current $i_c$ and the voltage $V_{be}$ were measured for increasing $V_{in}$. At some point, the current through the collector will be constant, due to the barrier in the forward-biased base-emitter region being lowered as much as possible by $V_{in}$, meaning that its maximum value follows Ohm’s law.

As we further increase $V_{in}$, we will find that $V_{be}$ will go towards a constant value. Why is that? Shouldn’t it increase too? I have great trouble understanding this last part.

I will appreciate any help!